# Laravel deployed to shared hosting not displaying image

Tags: laravel

I deployed a laravel app to shared hosting (hostinger). Everything is working fine except the images which are not showing up.

I have created a symlink of my storage folder with my public_html folder. Files uploaded enters the public folder but when I link the images they still do not show up.

I have created a symlink to the public_html since I cannot access the public folder. I need help on this please

I need the image to be displayed on the browser

Comment: You can't create symlinks on shared hosting `ln` linux command is disabled

Comment: There's a Laravel command for linking images to the `public` folder: `php artisan storage:link`; images are uploaded into the `storage` folder, then symlinked to `public`. Are you using this approach? Or something custom?

Comment: the public_html folder replaced the public folder. I used ssh to create a symlink already. the Link is between the public_html folder and the storage/app/public folder.

Comment: from my public_html folder i can see the symlinked folder but the link to the image does not work...

Comment: Is there anyway i can upload a screen shot here. so you can see what i really mean

Comment: yes, you can upload, just edit your question

Answer (score 0):

In default Laravel deployment the symlink is created in `public` folder as `storage` and links to `../storage/app/public`.

In order to debug your problem, please have a look at the developer tools of your browser to find out whether it is a 404 or 403 problem (or even another).

Please check for correct permissions. Otherwise you may change the physical storage path to something inside the `public` folder. This avoids the requirement to create a symlink. Keep in mind to protect non-public storage via `.htaccess` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to the path to your public assets directory if it is not `public` directory in the root folder. In your case, the public assets directory is `public_html`. So please bind the path to it from the root folder.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if (App::environment('prod')) {
            $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
                return base_path('../../public_html');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, remember to run 'php artisan config:cache' as per Laravel Deployment guidelines.
Running the command creates a general configuration file
in app/bootstrap/cache/config.php with all settings including directories and links that you should update